# Include static frameworks and libs on cocoapods

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods, podspec

After spending hours, I definitely need your help.

I want to create a pod including Spotify SDK ([here](https://github.com/spotify/ios-sdk), it's a **.framework**) and Deezer SDK ([here](https://cdns-files.dzcdn.net/developers/deezer-ios-sdk-v0.9.5-v00348824.zip), it's a ***.a lib**) in order to do some work with.

Both SDK are written in **Objective-C**, and I want to write my pod in **Swift** 2 (iOS 8). Also, projects that will include this pod are in Swift 2 (iOS 8).

After the creation of the pod project with `pod create lib` I started by trying to add **Spotify.framework** directly in the pod project, but can't compile...

So, I tried to include the Spotify.framework like a pod by writing a podspec, here is **spotify.podspec.json** :

```
{
  "name": "FakeSpotify",
  "version": "1.1",
  "summary": "Spotify iOS SDK",
  "homepage": "https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-ios-sdk/",
  "license": "MIT",
  "authors": {
    "jjt": "jeanjaques@thierry.com"
  },
  "source": {
    "git": "https://github.com/spotify/ios-sdk.git",
    "tag": "beta-13"
  },
  "platforms": {
    "ios": "8.0"
  },
  "requires_arc": true,
  "preserve_paths": "Spotify.framework",
  "public_header_files": "Spotify.framework/Versions/A/Headers/*.h",
  "vendored_frameworks": "Spotify.framework",
  "xcconfig": {
    "OTHER_LDFLAGS": "-ObjC"
  }
}
```

And I Also added a line on the **Podfile** :

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
use_frameworks!

target 'SpoTest_Example', :exclusive => true do
  pod 'SpoTest', :path => '../'
  pod 'FakeSpotify', :podspec => './spotify.podspec.json'
end

target 'SpoTest_Tests', :exclusive => true do
  pod 'SpoTest', :path => '../'
end
```

Now, after a `pod install`, a folder "FakeSpotify" is created with the the Spotify.framework in it. This part is ok, but it's not enough : I can't use it...

I can't import Spotify neither in the example project, nor in the development pods files (both in Swift).

I tried to add `#import <Spotify/Spotify.framework` in the umbrella file (SpoTest-umbrella.h), but there were an error : `Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'SpoTest'`.

After hitting myself and some search, I tried to edit my podfile by adding this post script :

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.build_configuration_list.build_configurations.each do |configuration|
        configuration.build_settings['CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES'] = 'YES'
    end
end
```

Nothing better, same error. Ok ok, what can I do ? Hmmm, I tried to remove the previously added import in umbrella file and I edited my pod podspec (SpoTest.podspec). I cried "ohhh I'm really bad, we need to also tell that we have a dependency in this podspec, even for development test...".

So I added this beautiful line : `s.dependency 'FakeSpotify'`

I was so happy, ... and so sad : new error from `pod install` command now :

```
[!] The 'Pods-SpoTest_Example' target has transitive dependencies that include static binaries: (/Users/jjt/Documents/dev/ios/LIBS/SpoTest/Example/Pods/FakeSpotify/Spotify.framework)
```

Ouch, so close ! Ok, let's try something to deal with it. I edited my Podfile by adding a pre install script :

```
pre_install do |installer|
    # workaround for https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3289
    def installer.verify_no_static_framework_transitive_dependencies; end
end
```

With this, the command line is ok, and the installation is done. But I still can't use it. And there is still an error if I import the framework in umbrella.

Do you have any more ideas ? I currently don't have more :)

Or maybe there is a better way without cocoapods ? My goal is to create a something with these two SDK, and to include it easily on others reals projects.

Thanks.